# Why do I encounter write-in Error with the new path created by vba?

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I tried to create a path when the path doesn't exist and save a file inside it with VBA.
However, I have encountered a write-in error each time I run the code below suggesting the path I just created doesn't exist. Meanwhile, if I look back at the path, it has been properly created.

Below is the code I use, could anyone help to solve the issue?

```
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & CampaignName & "-" & Format(Date, "mmdd") & "\"
If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & Path & """")
End If


FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & CampaignName & "-" & Format(Date, "mmdd") & "\test.html"


Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
fsT.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
fsT.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
fsT.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object
fsT.WriteText s
fsT.SaveToFile FileName, 2 'Save binary data To disk
```

Comment: Use this instead of a `Shell` command. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mkdir-statement

Comment: Also, it seems you do not define what `s` is...

Comment: Unrelated to your question but `FileName` can be simplified to `FileName = Path & "test.html"`, you already assigned the folder path to `Path` in the first place so why not use it?

Comment: @braX It does save the problem! Thank you!!!!  (Btw the s is defined in earlier steps so I didn't put the codes here)